# How to input an Excel Sheet matrix to R

Tags: r, input, matrix

I have an Excel Sheet with 300 Variables (Columns) and 400 Observations (Rows). I want to enter that sheet into R keeping the same setting and I want to keep it as a matrix hopefully to perform the regression analysis after.

Comment: This could be find in the about the second section of any R introductory text. People here are very nice and willing to help, but with the premise that we do our homework and try to Google first. I am a noob too and let's learn together! :D

Comment: Googling for 'r read excel file' will probably get you your answer, or at least the functions and packages you should use.

Answer (score 10):

Save the Excel file as a comma delimited CSV file, then import in R: `read.csv("(path of file)",header=T)`

Comment: obviously `header=T` is only needed if the CSV has an header (usually a good thing)

Comment: @nico, I believe `header = TRUE` is default for `read.csv` anyway, since most csv's tend to have a header (unlike `read.table`, where the default is `FALSE`).

Comment: You guys are unbelievable!...X=read.csv(file="RD.csv", header=TRUE) it works with me and I learned the other suggestions you've listed

Comment: You might want to join the R Public Chat Room :D

Answer (score 6):

There are various ways to read an Excel file into R.

The R manual gives some tips at this regard:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#Reading-Excel-spreadsheets

For instance you can use the `RODBC` package or the `xlsReadWrite` package.

However, I agree with @shirleywu that saving as csv is a better option, and gives a much larger compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

If you are new to R and you are having challenges like this you might want to consider working with RStudio (wwww.rstudio.org). RStudio is a front-end user interface for R and it has a neath feature on the right-hand-side, which helps you to upload upload CSV-files so you can use them in your analysis. In the screenshot below you see where the function is located. I assume that you know how to make a CSV file of an Excel document.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man and Yes I am totally new and using RStudio but I don't want to depend on RStudio only, I want to know the command syntax as well :-)....X=read.csv(file="RD.csv", header=TRUE) works with me

Comment: @AtheerAlAttar: When you use the feature in RStudio you will see the code showing up on the left part of the screen, which allows you to modify it easily. This is often handy as you don't have to retype the path and file names.